# how do i connect a plastic shower drain to my old metal sewer

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain

I am remodeling a shower how do i swap this drain,[image: new plastic drain] with my old drain[image], for my old school mortar shower pan?[image: picture to demonstrate]
this is how it looks like on top[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABS male adapter + teflon tape or joint compound.

[image]

Comment: what tools and procedures do I use to remove the old drain

Comment: It's pretty much just a pipe wrench job. You'll probably want two on hand--a second one to stabilize the fittings that will remain. Surely if you're building your own shower you have a basic understanding of fundamental plumbing techniques.

Comment: I cannot turn the wrench in between the joists.  I have added another picture

Comment: I have never done this before but I was thinking maybe I was supposed to cut the old pipe and join it with a Fernco connector

Comment: @joe - That's definitely the easy way, but not ideal. 2" internal pipe wrench? Even I don't own one of those... I'm trying to figure out if they used a drain key to install this (with which I think you'd have little hope of removing it with) or if they got a wrench in there. I'ma go with wrench. Sorrily, entropy does not apply to loosening pipes ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot turn the wrench in between the joists.

Say hello to my little friend! Which is called an *Enforcer* (that's just a length of pipe stuck over the end of your not-long-enough pipe wrench to extend its fulcrum - or to get a smaller wrench into where you need a larger one). You may need someone else to help keep the jaws from slipping before you can get any actual turning done.

You've just got to break the seal...

Be mean to it. If you hurt it, you can always just cut it out and use a rubber coupling. Or cut it further back and replace what you have to in PVC.